# Insert all values together with random values

Tags: sql, random, plsql

I have 3 tables : T1, T2 and T3
and I'm trying to insert data into T1 like so :

```
T1.DATA1 = random values from T3.DATA1
T1.DATA2 = T2.DATA2
T1.DATA3 = T2.DATA3
```

I have tried this query : I have tried this query :

```
INSERT INTO T1 (DATA1, DATA2, DATA3)
SELECT (SELECT DATA1 FROM
(SELECT DATA1 FROM T3
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1), DATA2, DATA3
FROM T2;
```

it returns correct values to `DATA2` and `DATA3`, but in `DATA1` I have one generated random value in all rows. How can I modify this query to have random value in every row ? `T2` contains around 3000 rows.

Comment: Is "DATA1 from T2 in random order" random enough? Or do you need something more?

Comment: Do you want to shuffle data from `DATA1` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subquery

```
SELECT DATA1 
FROM (SELECT DATA1 
      FROM T2
      ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
    WHERE rownum = 1
```

returns only one row, which then is repeated as many times as table `T2` contains rows. That's why our query doesn't work.
To insert values in random order (if I understood what you need):

```
INSERT INTO T1 (DATA1, DATA2, DATA3)
select tt.data1, t.data2, t.data3
  from (select t2.data2, t2.data3, rownum rn
        from t2) t,
       (select data1, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn
          from t3,
               (select rownum from dual connect by level <= 200) m) tt
 where t.rn = tt.rn
```

Some explanations: subquery `t` returns values of `data2` and `data3` columns of the `t2` table, subquery `tt` returns shuffled values of `t3.data1` column (values are ordered by dbms_random.value), then both subqueries are united in one. Subquery

```
select rownum from dual connect by level <= 200
```

is used to multiply rows. If `t3` table contains 15 rows, then result of the join with multiplying subquery produces 3000 rows, where each row from `t3` will be repeated 200 times. To multiply by another value, put it in the query instead of `200`.

Comment: thanks @Dmitry, I totally forgot I have there 3rd table, from which I need these random values. I edited my post, could you please edit your answer too ? I'm looking at your post and trying figure out how to achieve it

Comment: this query returns results only on number of rows from T3. My T1 is empty, T2 has 3000 rows and T3 has 15 rows. and this query returns only 15 rows with random values from T3 and values from T2.

Comment: @mauekunak You didn't mention that before. So what do need to do with values of `T2` and `T3`? Repeat `T3` values 200 times (to produce 3000 rows) or cut `T2`?

Comment: well T3 has primary key. I thought number of rows doesn't have to be the same, just put to T1.DATA1 any random value from T3.DATA1. if we need to repeat it to have 3000 rows, then yes, that's what I need

Comment: @mauekunak Updated again

Comment: what does 'm' stands for ? I get an error there when trying to execute query

Comment: great, got it working now, you helped me a lot, thank again Dmitry !